# python sqlalchemy not executing sql query

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm working with Python and sqlalchemy to empty tables stored in SQL Server. It seems that the SQL query, given as argument in `session.execute` function, simply does not execute. The table still contains data.

When I print and run the same query within SQL Server MS, it does exactly as expected.

Help is appreciated!

```
tableName = 'someTable'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('connectionString')
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
currentSession = Session()
query = 'IF ('
                       'EXISTS ('
                       'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES '
                       'WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = \'dbo\' '
                       'AND TABLE_NAME = \'%s\')) '
                       'BEGIN '
                       'DELETE FROM [database].[dbo].[%s] '
                       'END' % (tableName,tableName)
session.execute(query)
print(query)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you are not committing your transaction. Depending on your configuration, you will need to set [autocommit](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit) to True, or commit your transaction after execution (typically handled in multiple transactions that would require a rollback):

You can set this here:

```
sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=True)
```

or:

```
session.commit()
```

Reference to `sessionmaker()`:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. The first suggestion did not work, though the second solved the problem!

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad I could help!